# how remove domain when select image in CKeditor

Tags: laravel-5, ckeditor

How can I set CKEditor to always display the Relative URL vs the Absolute URL . I select an image using the CKFinder interface. In the Image Properties Window > URL Field after selecting an image it shows the relative url path. I would like it to show the relative http url. i.e. Display /directory/image.jpg rather then http://www.example.com/directory/image.jpg I'm using CKEditor 4  and laravel filemanager.Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean even for paths that aren't relative to the location of the CKEditor? Like for external URLs?

Comment: (Interesting... an [oposite but weirdly similar question from 2009](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/CKEditor-Image-Properties-Absolute-URL-vs-Relative-URL).)

Comment: no, just for my site